# r - Filter all entries showing two different factor values on common year

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a big dataset (3.2M entries) of water chemical compounds (Chem_ID) annual means organized by monitoring sites (Site_ID) and sampling years (Year) such as:

```
data= data.frame(Site_ID=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Chem_ID=c(A, B, B, A, C, C, A, A, B), Year=c(2001, 2001, 2003, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2002, 2003, 2004), AnnualMean=c(1.1, 1.2, 1.1, 2.1, 2.6, 3.1, 2.7, 2.6, 1.9))
```

I would like to filter only entries from monitoring sites that show a measurement for chemical compounds A and B on a common year. My Chem_IDs are factors. The result of this filter on the data.frame above would be:

```
data= data.frame(Site_ID=c(1, 1), Chem_ID=c(1, 2), Year=c(2001, 2001), AnnualMean=c(1.1, 1.2))
```

The end result is to filter as many pairs Chem_ID=A and Chem_ID=B from the same site and same years, to calculate as many ratios Chem_ID=1 / Chem_ID=2 as possible. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)

categs <- c('A', 'B')

data %>%
  group_by(Site_ID, Year) %>%
  filter(all(categs %in% as.character(Chem_ID)))
```

Or similarly in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

categs <- c('A', 'B')

setDT(data)[, .SD[all(categs %in% as.character(Chem_ID))], by = .(Site_ID, Year)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! When running the dplyr script I get the error: "NAs introduced by coercion". Any clues on where it comes from ?

Comment: Hard to say - you'd need to provide us with actual `dput` of your data.

Comment: I am sorry for being a rookie at this but what is dput ?

Comment: `dput(head(data, 10))` for first 10 rows of your data

Comment: Will do ! Another concern I add was that my Chem_ID are actually strings of charater and not values. Does that influence your code ? Sorry for being unclear

Comment: Yes it's probably linked to that, likely you have them as factor. But cannot say much without a `dput`.

Comment: Chem_IDs are factors in my data, I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Try the edit now. You just need to add any category you want to check for in `categs` vector.

Answer (score 0):

A base R option is using `subset` + `ave`

```
dataout <- subset(data,
                  as.logical(ave(as.character(Chem_ID),
                                 Site_ID,
                                 Year,
                                 FUN = function(v) all(c("A","B")%in%v))))
```

such that

```
> dataout
  Site_ID Chem_ID Year AnnualMean
1       1       A 2001        1.1
2       1       B 2001        1.2
```